# How to reset google apps account while transferring from godaddy to gmail?

Tags: web-hosting, g-suite, godaddy

I have a domain name and website on godaddy, and i used this tool to transfer my mails to gmail https://www.godaddy.com/gdshop/google/gmail%5Flogin.asp

After using this, i didn't receive any confirmation mails from google and can't create a google apps account, it says that this domain already registered.

Also when i send them to reset the admin password, they don't send anything.

I just want to know any ideas how to solve this?, or how to contact google regard this issue?

note: i want to use google apps standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by contacting google, and they helped me solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem with my own domain.  First I found the admin login link.  From there I followed the "forgot your password?" link.  That took me to a page that said something like "you don't have a secondary email address set up".  Then it asked me to type in an email address and create a CNAME under my domain that pointed to google.  I did it, waited until it propagated, then clicked the button that said I did it.  Then I got a message saying that someone would look into it in the next 48 hours.  Unfortunately that was around 96 hours ago and no response yet.  Still, that does seem to be the process to prove that you own a domain that was erroneously set up in google apps.

Hope that helps and good luck!